# Performance Issue on Somewhat Simple Query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, performance, database-performance

For the past few weeks I've been having a heck of a time increasing performance for a somewhat simple query. I suppose I'll write out the query first, then describe what is currently used and my ideas.

Table: ~100 million rows
Stats Gathered Weekly

example:

```
SELECT c1,c2,c3,c4,TO_NUMBER(c5)  
FROM TABLE  
WHERE CODE = 3 AND 
      NUMBER IN (115,433,54542,435930,22565,3293029,3222) AND
      DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-01-2010','DD-MM-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('01-01-2015','DD-MM-YYYY') AND
      AMOUNT > 1000
```

Currently there is an index on the CODE, NUMBER, and DATE columns that is being used, but the query still takes minutes to complete. There is also an index just on the NUMBER column that was tested out, and it performs slightly better but the query is still much too slow.
The table is also partitioned by DATE by month.

Because the existing indexes are not working, I am now going to create my own table which I have free reign over.

My ideas are:
1) Create a partition or materialized view on CODE; half the table has code = 3, so my thinking is that this will effectively half the table size.
2) DATE is actually saved with time as well; truncating all dates and creating a partition in this way may increase performance.
3) Create an index on all four columns to see if it will increase performance.

That's all I really have. Any other suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Partition by range on DATE.

Comment: Please show explain plan output.

Answer (score 1):

You say the table is partitioned based on the `DATE` column (presumably you mean range partitions).

You say you have indexes, but you don't specify if they are global (one index covering all partitions) or local (one index for each partition).

Any attempt I make to come up with advice involves guessing at how Oracle is executing the query now; and it seems like there are a variety of possible plans it could be using.

So my primary advice is to learn how to view and understand the execution plan.  You need to understand what it is doing in order to have any real idea of what might make it better.

But I will make some suggestions that may or may not be applicable.

Assuming your indexes are global, then I think the optimizer has the option to *either* do partition elimination based on `DATE` (in which case it is full-scanning the relevant partitions) *or* do lookups using the index.  It's possible you would get an improvement by using a local index, because it could do partition elimination and then use an index lookup within each partition (in this case, having `DATE` in the index would be pointless, at least for this query).

Possibly, adding `AMOUNT` to the index would help, but this depends on whether `AMOUNT > 1000` eliminates a significant number of rows.

You could potentially create an index that covers all the filter columns and all the selected columns, in which case the query could be satisfied by index lookups without looking at the table at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague on the actual index that is in place.

For this query, the best index is on `(code, number, date, amount)`.

However, you are fetching back 5 years worth of data from a table with 100,000,000 rows.  I don't know how selective the other columns are, but that is potentially a lot of data being returned.  That might explain the performance issue.

Comment: @onedaywhen . . . `code` should be first because it has an equality condition.